# Domain Controller reboot disrupts Web Servers

Tags: domain-controller

We have 3 DCs in our environment running AD, DNS and DHCP on a Win2k8 R2 OS. We reboot our servers monthly on different days to apply security patches. During the reboots we would get some complaints from users that they lose connectivity to our intranet sites. I know it's directly related to the reboots since our intranet web servers are authenticated to these controllers. But I was hoping someone could explain and help me understand the reasons that my web server fails?

Comment: If one of your DC/DNS servers is down and the clients are trying to use that DC/DNS server to resolve the FQDN of the web server or web site then that would explain the failure to access the site. If the clients don't have the DNS records for the server or site cached then they'll need to query the DC/DNS server and if it's down that won't happen.

Comment: All DCs are running DNS but only 1 DC is down at any given time. We schedule the reboots on different hours of the day.

Answer (score 4):

Probably because the servers hosting your intranet are unable to authenticate users, with all your domain controllers being down.  Likewise, if your intranet serves content hosted on other domain servers, those servers may be unable to authenticate the web servers to allow them to access whatever resource they need.

The proper approach is to stagger your domain controller reboots.  Reboot one, wait until it's back online.  Then reboot the next.  Repeat.

Comment: We do stagger the reboots on different hours. The contents of the web site is either static or data that is gathered from backend sql. I'm thinking it does have to do with the web server authenticated to the dc that is being rebooted but our reboots usually are not more than 5 min and I thought cached credentials might come into play during those 5 min of outage.

Comment: @rmnv That sounds like you might not have your secondary DNS configured or not configured properly.  I'd check the DNS config of the webservers, SQL server, and the clients who complain as well.  Could also be an issue of not having an [accessible global catalog](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc728188%28v=ws.10%29.aspx), depending on how your environment is setup.

Answer (score 0):

Did I understand correctly, you reboot them on different days.  If not you need to follow HopelessN00b's advice.

I have seen this when a system or process depends on FSMO role such as PDC emulator.  If you have the same issue when you reboot each DC then this is not relevant.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc223752.aspx

Comment: we do stagger our reboots but we still have had complaints during a reboot of a dc whose role Is not a pdc emulator.

Comment: At an appropriate time:
I would start troubleshooting this by opening tcpview (from MS sysinternals) on the web server, then from a desktop connect to the site.  Watch for connections.  

Then reboot the DC and watch the connections drop.  You should be able to verify the application and port used.  The port will help to identify the protocol.  You might have to do this a couple of times.

Another option is to dig into the Web server settings and see how the authentication is setup.  Do you know if it is using IIS or Apache?

Comment: I will download the tcpview software and try that out on Monday. The web servers are IIS and I believe there are multiple app pools using Integrated authentication with a domain account.